# Rearrange matrix by a condition

Tags: r, matrix

I'd like to rearrange one matrix with a condition. If I have a data frame:

```
# My data frame
my_DF<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4)
my_DF
```

and I need to convert it into a matrix, usually I do:

```
# matrix convertion
myMX<-matrix(my_DF, ncol=7,nrow=4)
myMX
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]    1    1    2    2    3    3    4
[2,]    1    1    2    2    3    4    4
[3,]    1    1    2    3    3    4    4
[4,]    1    2    2    3    3    4    4
```

But this solution doesn't return the desired output, as shown below:

```
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
     1    1    1    1    1    1    1
     2    2    2    2    2    2    2
     3    3    3    3    3    3    3
     4    4    4    4    4    4    4
```

What I can do to reach my desired solution?

Comment: `matrix(my_DF, ncol=7,nrow=4, byrow=T)` will do it.

Comment: @lmo - Convert that to an answer unless you think the question should be closed.

Comment: @Dason Thanks. I've entered it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

By default, R will fill in data by column in a matrix. What you want to do is to fill it in by row instead. The most straightforward way to do this is to use the byrow=TRUE argument.

```
matrix(my_DF, ncol=7,nrow=4, byrow=TRUE)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
[2,]    2    2    2    2    2    2    2
[3,]    3    3    3    3    3    3    3
[4,]    4    4    4    4    4    4    4
```